# Upload Error: 403 Forbidden response with DigitalOcean

Tags: craft3, upload, digitalocean

This is the error I get when uploading files through the front end and Craft admin into a docs folder on my DigitalOcean s3 instance (bucket name is changed to test).

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://test.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=content%2Fdocs%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: GET https://test.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=content%2Fdocs%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url` resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: AccessDeniedtesttx0000 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): - AccessDeniedtesttx0000000000000199322ec-005cdc1c7b-10e1ef4-ams3a10e1ef4-ams3a-ams3`
```

What does this error mean?

I wondered if it was an issue with the CDN settings? After I noticed images were loading in slowly I began using the following in my config for DigitalOcean - which loads in images faster. Then I noticed that I can no longer upload files through front end forms into volumes set up with DigitalOcean. Also some of my templates are not using the full path referencing the cdn...

```
'SPACES_API_KEY' => 'XXXXXXX',
'SPACES_SECRET' => 'XXXXXXX',
'SPACES_ENDPOINT' => 'https://ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com',
'SPACES_REGION' => 'ams3',
'SPACES_BUCKET' => 'test',
'SPACES_URL' => 'https://test.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com',
```